# How can i make calculations on specific rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make calculations on specific rows by this formula

=($B$2-B3)+($C$2-C3)

I need every time to change number of cell only like

=($B$3-B4)+($C$3-C4)

and the result will every time in a different column every time need to add +1 to number of cell ( same row )

how can i do that as i need to complete my calculations as in this example 28 times.

I attached example i made it manually but i have data more than this example

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: if I understand it correctly then in D2 instead of `$B$2` you could use `OFFSET($B$1,$A2,0)`, similarly for `$C$2`

Comment: Thanks for replying .. i tried to use you solution but i got the right number only in the first still but in the other cell is wrong ...  i need to implement the equation =($B$2-B3)+($C$2-C3) in D1 then drag it down to get the results of the other cell exists in same column ... then in E1 need to take =($B$3-B4)+($C$3-C4) and do the same thing ... and in F1 and so on until i finish all 28 data .. i have 2000 data in real but here i'm trying to post it as an example .. i hope you can understand what i need :-(

Comment: i don't need to write the equation 2000 times to implement all cells .. is there any formula or equation can increase the number of cell ?

Comment: Do you have O365? I think it should be possible to write a spill formula to do it in one go.

Comment: @TomSharpe  excuse me what do you mean by O365 ?

Comment: Officially called Microsoft 365 - the latest version of Office which contains Excel having some new features like spill formulas https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in D2 put

```
=(OFFSET($B$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D1),0)-$B3)+(OFFSET($C$2,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D1),0)-$C3)
```

it offsets the number of rows based on a column difference from column D
it also locks columns witl $B3 and $C3, so that you can copy foemula to the left
result
[image]

Comment: thanks for your helping . Unfortunately i tried it but got wrong results as i expected

Comment: are you sure you replicated the steps correctly? I get exactly the same results you did in the third picture

Comment: Thanks it is done but can i make the results in same column

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, a spill formula in O365 would look like this:

```
=IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$2:$A$29))>=ROW($A$2:$A$29),"",INDEX(B:B,TRANSPOSE(ROW($B$2:$B$29)))-$B$2:$B$29+INDEX(C:C,TRANSPOSE(ROW($C$2:$C$29)))-$C$2:$C$29)
```

If you didn't have O365, the equivalent pull-down formula would be:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)>=ROW(A1),"",INDEX(B:B,COLUMN(B1))-$B2+INDEX(C:C,COLUMN(B1))-$C2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your helping i will try it too .. Thanks again